# Chrome Extension detect url with parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code that will block a js url and redirects to my modified js url. The url that is trying to block has a parameter (ex. version #492) and it changes quite often. The problem is I have to update the parameter every time the parameter changes which is inconvenient. Is there a way to detect this url without me having to manually update it every time?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return {redirectUrl:("mydomain.com/modified.js")};
    }, 
    { urls: ["domain.com/assets/main.js?492"]},
        ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Hey, Louis! I dont think this is worthy of writing in an answer, but please try using RegEx!

Comment: Simply replace 492 with `*`